# php undefined variable for a function

Tags: php

so as i mentioned in comments the first one shows but the second one does not show and gives me unidentified error  i could just pass it to the function but is that normal ?

```
    echo $add;//this one shows normally
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
        if($_POST['formname']=="Signup Form")
            SignUp();
        else if($_POST['formname']=="Signin Form")
            SignIn();
    function SignUp(){
        echo $add; //this one give me unidentified erro
        $bool = true;
        //some code
    }
```

Comment: Sidenote: I'm assuming..... that your form name is `<form name="Signin Form" ...>` if it is, then you can't have spaces seperating the words for named elements. `if($_POST['formname']=="Signup Form")` use an underscore instead of a space; IF that's the case here.

Comment: Yes you need to check the scope of the variable and its outside your function. If you want to make it available inside the function you must pass it as function argument or make the variable as GLOBAL

Comment: Read up on variable scope: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Read about [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Not related to the question, but please consider putting brackets on your `if` statements. No, they are not strictly necessary, but it makes nested `if`s very hard to read, especially the non-edited version where they weren't indented. Saving the 6 characters is NOT worth the damage to readability.

Answer (score 4):

```
function SignUp()
        {
```

to

```
function SignUp()
    global $add;
        {
```

Or, better, change it to:

```
function SignUp($add)
        {
```

and change your call to `SignUp($add);`.

The first version (with `global`) appears to be much tidier, but it makes things much more complex as time goes on. In hindsight I wish I hadn't learnt about `global` so early on – it's rarely (ever?) the right approach.

Comment: *"Or, better, change it to:"* `function SignUp($add)` is indeed better.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring it as a global in the function:

```
function SignUp(){

 global $add;

 echo $add;`
```

Comment: [Why global state is the devil, and how to avoid using it](http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as argument

```
function SignUp($add)
{
    echo $add;
}
```

or Make it global

```
function SignUp()
{
    global $add;
    echo $add;
}
```

You can dig more into Variable Scope  [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

Read princip of variable scope visibilities in php, answer on your question is second example. In body of function you're looking for local scope variable, you can easy make your variable **global**.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php